# Params not being passed to new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I have a form in the view:

```
<%= form_tag(new_admin_course_path(chichi: @provider.id), {method: :get}) do %>
    <%= submit_tag I18n.t('views.courses.index.add_new') %>
<% end %>
```

`@provider.id` is equal to 1 (checked with `Pry`).

`new_admin_course_path` lands in `courses_controller#new`. From the action itself (with `binding.pry` help) I got the content of `params` and this is what I found:

```
pry(#<Admin::CoursesController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Add course", "controller"=>"admin/courses", "action"=>"new"}
```

I'm not new in Rails, but I have no idea why this is happening and I'm not getting what I pass through the helper method.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you using a form to generate a `GET` request? This could just be a standard link tag, styled up as a button.

Comment: Or `button_to` helper which does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to pass your `chichi` parameter, you could use [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to), which basically creates an empty form (you can pass params through):

```
<%= button_to I18n.t('views.courses.index.add_new'), new_admin_course_path, method: :get, params: { chichi: @provider.id } %>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
Use This one:

<%= form_tag(new_admin_course_path(chichi: @provider.id), method: :get) do %>
    <%= submit_tag I18n.t('views.courses.index.add_new') %>
<% end %>
```